# css 100vh is not setting the div to 100% height

Tags: html, css

As seen in the below screenshot

[image]

the viewport height is covered around 97% and not 100%. the next section can be seen. I am stuck with this issue for a couple of hours now, below is my css and html code

css

```
html, body {
     width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.section-3 {
    background: url(../images/section-3-bg.jpg) center center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height:100vh;
}
```

HTML

```
<section class="section-3 col-xs-12" id="demand">
    <section class="container">
        <center>
            <div id="trapezium"></div>
                <h1 class="blue big-font">On Demand Charters</h1>
                <img src="images/demand-border.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="width:auto;">
                <div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-2">
                <p class="medium-font">With Powerfly, access a range of aircraft from light 
                                       to large jets, turboprops and helicopters 
                                       either through on-demand charters. All you need to
                                       do is book and a Powerfly executive will customise
                                       your plan as per your needs.
                </p>
                <h2 class="explore-btn"><a href="demand.html">Details</a></h2>
            </div>
        </center>
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: the mention code is perfect you need to show more code or give site link

Comment: body margin/padding?

Comment: I would suggest avoiding using VH as some Safari version get quite buggy with it (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Comment: Cannot reproduce - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yOqBwL That said `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used. Also we don;t know the CSS related to the inner elements (especially the "trapezium" div).

Comment: website link http://mindstack.in/powerfly/

Comment: Looks  like a ZOOM issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D can you please check in firefox too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is the carousel!

```
#carousel-generic-1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine .. You didn't take a complete screenshot of the `section` but it actually take the place it should.

However, it cuts the button because of the `height: 100vh;`

[image]

Comment: As @Paulie_D said, looks like a zoom issue of your browser.

Comment: can you check in firefox?

Comment: Same result in Firefox V.45 as in Chrome V.49

Comment: Sorry but vh works fine, the problem is in another place.